# How to proactively prevent termite infestation

Tags: drainage, moisture, termite, ants, sewage

I'm seeing ants boring holes through Tiles and ejecting sand and I'm told ants are first to come then comes the Termite.

Outside my building I'm seeing lots of ant colonies where if can lay our feet , it just starts biting.

[image]

[image]

I have 6 Sewage pits( made of concrete ring ) around my building.

As far as I understand , soil with moisture around the house is invitation for the Termites.

[image]

[image]

Please find detailed videos here ( [1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tHSitIxg8Rcq8tgbv7tGf5qFfSfxhgqq/view?usp=sharing) , [2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mITg0oWOYoWc6zaZzsQLR5ARbxEZ4W2l/view?usp=sharing) ).

What are the pro-active steps that I can take to prevent my house from become target for Dampwood / Drywood /Subterranean Termites,Swarms,Carpenter Ants and other boring insects.

FYI:
There's a termite infestation on the banks of small water irrigation canal which is 100 feet away.

**Update:** - When it rains , I see the flying insects making its way in and around the home.  Could it be a boring insect or some kind of flying termite ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It’s probably too late now, but avoid burying pieces of wood. Where in the world are you?

Comment: I'm from India.Can I see some plants so that it'll take the moisture away from soil.. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

- Dig a trench around the perimeter of house.
- Buy some high quality anti termite chemicals such as Termador and mix that with less water and pour it on the trench around the house. Give it couple of weeks to get absorbed the soil below. This will kill the subterranian termites
- Make sure there's no paper or cardboard box or wood around the house this will draw the damp or dry wood termites.
- Keep you windows and other holes covered with mosquito net , this will prevent flying termites from entering into home.
- Keep the wood items dry in your house.
- Keep an eye on any mud tunnels around and in the house.If you ever spot any remove it physically first and apply or pour Termador kind of chemicals on it so the Termite colony would get destroyed
- BAIT STATION is another approach to kill off any neighboring Termite colonies. Basically you will have to buy and install the bait station around the house , the cellulose in the bait station , lures the worker termites and when it feeds , it'll die off along with its colony.

My Recommendation:

-> Chemical approach first( to mark off your house from termites )

-> Bait station ( to kill off any neighbhoring Termite colonies .. imagine termites growing in a tree stump near by your house , it's just matter of time .. when the root reaches under your house foundation these Sub terranian Termites can travel and come in to your house easily.

-> Keep the items( Paper, dry/wet wood ) away from the permitter of house

-> Mosquito net